# FFMPEG Chunk too big?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a sequence of .png files, and I am trying to convert them into a movie. The problem is that when I try and convert it to avi format, ffmpeg says ***"chunk too big"***:.

I am running the command:

ffmpeg -f image2 -i images%d.png -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 22 -threads 0 output_video.avi

How do I fix it so that I get a movie that works with PowerPoint?
I've gone through trying various encoding schemes, and referred to: 
[Lossless universal video format](https://superuser.com/questions/486325/lossless-universal-video-format/522853#522853) for the initial command.

Log:

```
fmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
 configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.7.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'images%d.png':
Duration: 00:00:12.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 927x1152, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 5.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
Output #0, avi, to 'output_video.avi':
Metadata:
ISFT            : Lavf56.36.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p, 927x1152, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))

> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[png @ 0x7fed82e89e00] chunk too big  92kB time=00:00:07.12 bitrate= 106.2kbits/s    
frame=  299 fps= 61 q=-1.0 Lsize=     202kB time=00:00:11.88 bitrate= 139.1kbits/s    
video:189kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 6.723067%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.68  size: 46814
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] frame P:46    Avg QP:18.10  size:  1270
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] frame B:251   Avg QP:17.13  size:   166
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  0.7%  2.0%  6.7%  6.7% 18.1% 18.7% 37.5%  9.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] mb I  I16..4: 20.3% 59.4% 20.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.2%  P16..4:  0.5%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.4%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.5%  L0:65.2% L1:34.6% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] 8x8 transform intra:57.2% inter:5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] direct mvs  spatial:97.2% temporal:2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] coded y,u,v intra: 12.5% 5.2% 5.1% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 69% 28%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 65%  6% 29%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 20% 19%  3%  4%  4%  4%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] ref P L0: 53.9%  2.6% 28.5%  5.2%  3.1%  2.8%  1.2%  0.8%  0.5%  0.3%  0.1%  0.2%  0.2%  0.2%  0.2%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] ref B L0: 42.7% 19.9%  7.0%  5.6%  3.7%  3.7%  2.7%  2.7%  2.1%  2.7%  2.1%  2.2%  1.7%  1.0%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] ref B L1: 94.7%  5.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fed82138e00] kb/s:129.51
```

Comment: Looks like: https://mbudisic.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/converting-a-sequence-of-pngs-to-a-quicktime-movie/ has some use in this case, but it still is not playing it back in a useful format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it to be AVI, then try

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i images%d.png -vf scale=928x1152,setsar=1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -coder 0 -preset veryslow -crf 22 -threads 0 output_video.avi
```

But try MP4 first

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i images%d.png -vf scale=928x1152,setsar=1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -coder 0 -preset veryslow -crf 22 -threads 0 output_video.mp4
```

FFmpeg will assume a framerate of 25 for the image sequence (and thus preserve it in the output). You can change that by adding `-framerate N` before `-i` where `N` is your sequence framerate.

Comment: Running into issue saying "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height". Looking into trying to adjust bit rate, rate, width, or height.

Comment: Try revised command. Your dimensions should be multiple of 2.

Comment: Well done. This looks like it fixed the problem of the output however. Chunk is still reading too big but the scale set correctly and the -pix_fmt seems to have made a huge difference. Still verifying...

Comment: That chunk error is due to the 179th PNG file, not in the ffmpeg output.

Comment: I will award you the answer. Thanks. One quick question: I'm staring at the output and I don't see a single thing about a 179 file. Upon chunk error it produces: [png @ 0x7fed82e89e00] chunk too big  92kB time=00:00:07.12 bitrate= 106.2kbits/s    I don't see any 179. How did you know?

Comment: FFmpeg is using a framerate of 25 and the errant PNG is at 07:12 which is the 179th frame.