# On my Intel Core i9-12900K only the efficient cores are executed with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

On my Intel Core i9-12900K only the efficient cores are executed with FFMPEG (see picture). What could be the reason for this and how can I change it? Screenshot System Utilization with FFMPEG.

Thank you in advance for help.

Screenshot with FFMPEG:
[image: Screenshot with FFMPEG]

Comment: Is there a problem here? What is your desired behavior and what evidence do you have that something is actually wrong or broken?

Comment: See the comments and linked answers on this similar thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1418816/how-to-utilize-all-cores-on-high-end-cpus-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Interesting... Please post the command line you are using and the version of FFmpeg (it's recommended to try the latest stable release). Try `-threads 24` before and after `-i`. Example: `ffmpeg -threads 24 -i input.mkv -threads 24 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4`. If filters are used, try also adding `-filter_threads 24`

Comment: It does not depend on ffmpeg alone, but on the used encoding library.

Comment: Without knowing the used command line parameters i suppose this is a duplicate of [How many threads does ffmpeg use by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/155305/how-many-threads-does-ffmpeg-use-by-default)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Most of the linked SU posts are about increasing core count. This is about not using the E cores. So a core affinity issue. It's pretty easy to solve on windows.

Comment: Hi Rotem, thank you very much for your infos & comments. After some tests I found this solution. ffmpeg version: N-108207-g4ba68630ca-20220919 >> ffmpeg -threads 16 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "%_infile%" -c:v hevc_nvenc -profile:v main10 -pix_fmt p010le -rc:v:0 vbr -tune hq -rc-lookahead 90 -spatial-aq 1 -aq-strength 8 -cq 30 -qmin 3 -qmax 69 -preset slow -vf scale=%_scale% -b:v %_stdbr% -maxrate:v %_maxbr% -movflags faststart -threads 8 -gpu 1 -c:a copy "%_outfile%.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Hey on Windows 10 and 11 I think you can force it onto the P cores using Task Manager.

Here is an article about [forcing core affinity](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-manually-allocate-cpu-cores-windows-10/)

This should allow you to force it onto the P cores and prevent use of the E cores.

Edit:

Increasing the core count might also have the same effect for different reasons.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It would be preferable to not write an answer that could contain information that will probably be incorrect after the next windows update or two.